# Insert Chapter number in header or footer in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word

I'd like to have the chapter number in a Word 2016 document's header. I do not see this in the 'Insert Field' options. There is a section number, but I want the header to tell the reader which chapter it is reading, not the section, which do not correspond with the chapters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have used a style for your chapter headings (eg Heading 1), you can use the STYLEREF field in the Insert Field dialog.

You'll see on the right of the dialog options which allow you to insert just the paragraph number (otherwies by default the text with style applied is inserted).

Comment: tried it, and yes, easy! In Word 2016, you can pick the style first, and then add \n for just the paragraph number. In my case, the Field Code was STYLEREF "Heading 1"\n

Answer (score 4):

#### I'd like to have the chapter number in a Word 2016 document's header

You can number your chapter headings.

You can also customise the numbers, for example to add "Chapter" before each numbers.

See below for instructions for Word 2010 and Word 2013 (Word 2016 should be similar).

---

#### Automatic Chapter and Subsection Numbering

> Word can automatically number sections (Chapter 1, 1.1, 1.2, etc.) of
>   your document and include the chapter number in the captions (Figure
>   1.2, 2.2, etc.).
>
> 1. Make sure each of your chapter titles are in the Heading 1 style, and then click on one of your chapter titles.
> 2. If you just need the chapter number included in captions, on the On the Home Ribbon, in the Paragraph Group, click the Multilevel List
>      icon and select the one with the words Chapter 1 in it from the List
>      Library section.
>
>    <kbd>[image]</kbd>
>
>    If you need subsections numbered (for example, 2.1, 2.2, 2.12, etc.)
>      as well, then choose the list the 1 Heading 1; 1.1 Heading 2, etc.
>      option (right side, middle row). Note that doing this once sets the
>      formatting for all heading levels.
> 3. Click OK when you are finished.
> 4. If you typed in the text “Chapter #”, and now it is duplicating your efforts, delete the text you typed and leave the automatically
>      generated chapter number.
> 5. To follow the automatically generated chapter number with the title of your chapter on a new line, click just before the text of
>      your title, hold down the Shift key on the keyboard, and then press
>      the Enter key.
>
> Note: If you have any problems with word automatically adding outline
>   numbering to parts of your front matter, simply delete it.  Your
>   chapter numbers will reset to show the correct number of chapters.

Source [Automatic Chapter and Subsection Numbering](http://guides.lib.umich.edu/c.php?g=283073&p=1886004)

---

#### Customizing Your Numbers

> If you want to change anything about the numbers – for example, you
>   are using the 1.1, 1.2, etc. style but would like the word “Chapter”
>   to display automatically in front of the Heading 1 number, you want to
>   change Arabic numbers to Ordinal, or you want to change the spacing
>   after the numbers, you can.
>
> Click one of your headings, then go back to the Home Ribbon, and in
>   the Paragraph Group click the Multilevel List icon (see screen shot
>   above) and select Define New Multilevel List….  Click the More>>
>   button, then select the relevant list level.
>
> - You can use the Number style for this level: pulldown menu to choose from a various styles, as seen in the screenshot (below the
>     Enter formatting for number: box).
> - In the screenshot, with the Level on the left set at 1, we added the word “Chapter”. Moving to the second level, you can change the
>     period in between the level and sublevel to a dash or anything you
>     want in the Number format box.
> - You can also see that a tab follows the number – you can change it to a space or none. You may have to adjust this if the alignment
>     seems off.
>
>   <kbd>[image]</kbd>

Source [Automatic Chapter and Subsection Numbering](http://guides.lib.umich.edu/c.php?g=283073&p=1886004)

---

#### I want to add the chapter number to the document's header or footer

To do this you can take advantage  of the `seq` field.

> Create your Chapter Names using the format:
>
> ```
>     Chapter {SEQ chap \r1} title1
>     Chapter {SEQ chap \r2} title2
>     Chapter {SEQ chap \r3} title3
>     ...
> ```
>
> Where:
>
> - `chap` is the `sequence identifier`,
> - `\r` indicates that the sequence starts with the number following it.
>
> The only difference for each chapter is to to change the number
>   following the `\r` switch and the chapter title.
>
> In the header or footer of each chapter (wherever your page numbers occur) you can then use the following:
>
> ```
>     {SEQ chap \c}-{PAGE}
> ```
>
> This results in the same sequence number (the chapter number) being
>   used over and over again, followed by a dash and the actual page
>   number.

Source [Using RD Fields with Chapter Headings](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T008557_Using_RD_Fields_with_Chapter_Headings.html)

Comment: thanks for the effort, but it wasn't the question. I wanted to know how the Field Code for chapter number so that I could add this number to the document's header or footer.

Comment: Answer updated. See the new section at the bottom.

Comment: sounds good! I do not have time to check today, but will let you know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: where to "Create your Chapter Names using the format:"? This part is not really clear to me. I can add a field code to the footer, and under options there are Field Specific Switches (including \c) but I do not get the 'chap' part or where to create or modify this (and neither do I get the \r) part.

Comment: You put some field codes in your heading. `chap` is a variable name and `\r` says the variable stores a number `x`, where `x` is the number after `\r`. In the footer `chap` is the variable name and `\c` picks up the value of the number `x` assigned in the heading.

Comment: "You put some field codes in your heading", but the page "Using RD Fields with Chapter Headings" says "at the beginning of the chapter's document:" -- what then? Why would I create my chapter names using seq if those are already entered in the document and available?