# Word 2016 Header Link to Section

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, headers

I am writing a project summary and want to have a header on each page to indicate the section and/or subsection that page includes. For example, a subsection spans a few pages and I want the reader to be able to flip that page and determine based on the header what subsection s/he is currently viewing.
I have seen a couple of [related questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1078573/insert-chapter-number-in-header-or-footer-in-word-2016), but they aren't perfectly applicable.

Should I format the subsection under Styles and link it to a header somehow? I don't want to manually type in each page's contents to the header for the corresponding page.

Below is an example of my report format. There are no numbers or special styles included.

***Section***

blah blah blah...

**Subsection**

blah blah blah...

Comment: One of the answers you reference suggests using STYLEREF fields, which would require that you apply styles to the section and subsection headings. You say that they aren’t perfectly applicable so can you spell out why that doesn’t work for your situation.